# create comma-separated list in xtend

Tags: xtend

I am learning xtend. What would be a nice way to create a comma separated list in xtend? (something like the SEPARATOR in xpand)

I want to produce a comma separated list of parameters in my generator:

```
«FOR param: row.params»
     "«param.value»",
«ENDFOR»
```

This works but I need to omit the last comma. I tried row.params.join(",") as well but then the quotes are missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to try

```
«FOR param: row.params SEPARATOR ','»
     "«param.value»"
«ENDFOR»
```

or

```
row.params.join(',') [ value ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
row.params.join(', ')[''' "value" ''']
```

should do the trick. I put spaces before and after double quotes only to help you seeing each chars, but you may want to delete them.